# What is the 3D volume enclosed by 3 n-dimensional vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, volume

I have 3 n-dimensional vectors and I wanted to compute the 3d volume enclosed by them. I had the following process in mind.

1. Perform Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization of the 3 vectors to obtain an orthonormal basis.
2. Compute the coefficients of the 3 vectors wrt the orthonormal basis.
3. Compute the determinant of the resultant coefficient matrix.

Is there a simpler approach to do this that doesn't involve basis computation?

Comment: You might look up Gram determinant.

Comment: Thanks, That was really useful.